# Import data to Neo4j Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, neo4j

I am currently running Neo4j with 3 core servers and 3 replicas within my Kubernetes (PKS) environment. I am able to successfully connect to the remote cluster from my local machine via Neo4j desktop. I am now trying to import a large (3gb) CSV file from our Hadoop environment into the Neo4j cluster. I downloaded the file on my local machine and was able to use "neo4j-admin import" to create a graph.db. I am now wondering how to get that graph.bd or csv file directly into the Neo4j Kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 0):

The documented way to transfer a neo4j DB is to use:

- The `neo4j-admin dump` command on the originating machine to create a dump file.
- The `neo4j-admin load` command on the destination machine to fill a fresh DB from that dump file.

Refer to [the documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/dump-load/) for more details.

Comment: What would be the syntax to load from a local machine to the cluster? How do I get that new DB from my machine into the Kubernetes cluster? Would I need to run "kubectl cp" to move the graph.db file from local to the leader pod then load?